# Modal Form to be triggered by if statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

So i'm building a webpage, and everything on it, but one thing works fine.
So on my "MDT" page, i select a status (eg State 0, which sends "Panic Button"), and its sent through to the database. When control.html checks the database (Every second), and picks up the "status" column saying "Panic Button", it plays an alarm. That alarm ends when my status changes.

What i want is as well as an alarm, a modal form to pop up with basic details (eg Active State 0, Call sign, name etc)

What i have so far:

```
<center><h2>Available Units</h2>
                    <div id="units">
                        <ul class="units">
                            <?php
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM mdt WHERE CAD = 'NULL';";
                                $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo '<li class="' . statusToClass(displayData($row['status'])) . '">' . displayData($row['callsign']) . ' - ' . displayData($row['name']) . ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog editUnitBtn" aria-hidden="true"></span><br/>Status: ' . displayData($row['status']) . '</li>';
                                }
                            ?>
                            <?php
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM mdt WHERE status = 'Panic Button';";
                                $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo '<audio autoplay="false" src="panic.mp3">';
                                    sleep(2);
                                    }
                            ?>
                            <?php
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM mdt WHERE status = 'Panic Button';";
                                $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
                                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                     echo "<script>$('#panicModal').modal('show')</script>";
                                     }
                            ?>
```

Then near the bottom of the page:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="panicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ATTENTION - ACTIVE STATE 0</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mdt WHERE status = 'Panic Button';";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        ?>
        <label>Callsign</label>
        <?php echo displayData($row['callsign']); ?>
        <Label>Collar Number</label>
        <?php echo displayData($row['name']); ?> 
        <Label>Last Known Location</label>
        <?php   
        if (displayData($row['CAD']) == "NULL") {
        echo ' <i>Currently unassigned</i>';
        } else {            
        $cadid = displayData($row['CAD']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cads WHERE id = '$cadid';";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
        echo displayData($row['location']); } ?> 
        <Label>Call Type</label>
        <?php           
        if (displayData($row['CAD']) == "NULL") {
        echo ' <i>Currently unassigned</i>';
        } else {
        $cadid = displayData($row['CAD']);
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM cads WHERE id = '$cadid';";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
        echo displayData($row['type']); } ?> 
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Any Idea's? Somewhere on the internet it mentioned putting jquery at the top of the page but when i do this it makes no difference and depending on where i put it, stops all js functions working. However with the jquery script at the bottom, everything works fine bar this bit.

control.html : https://pastebin.com/9u6Su1uD
control.js : https://pastebin.com/1FeXUN6b

Any help would be much appreciated.
TIA
Tyler

Comment: Your jQuery should trigger the modal regardless of where you actually include jQuery in your file. When you place it in your `<head>`, you say it breaks other JS functionality. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Yeah sorry ignore that, i placed it wrong i think. I just moved it to the top of the page and still works, but this modal popup isn't

Comment: My guess is that it's because your're not actually closing your MySQLi connection, and thus, your third query isn't getting executed. I'd try moving the echoed `<script>` to be in the second `.units` PHP block. If that doesn't work, try debugging to check that the `$row` is actually returning data.

Comment: @ObsidianAge so now it looks like this: [link]https://pastebin.com/RVPqatf9 still doesn't work. Checked and the $row is deffo returning data otherwise the panic button alarm wouldn't work etc

Comment: Okay made progress. So i opened the f12 console, and pasted in $('#panicModal').modal('show') which resulted in this: [link](https://gyazo.com/353a01b48b92f50ef1452653fec2b2ab) . So it's opening and there, just not activating when the alarm goes off when the webpage finds "Panic Button" in the status column. Plus the formating is wrong, it looks like the sql query's in the modal isn't executing.